# Xcode: how do I change the font and the font size of red or yellow messages

Tags: xcode, fonts

how do I change the font size of the yellow or red error- or warning messages? I have in the Preferences everything(?) tried...

Comment: You might have to change the overall font size in system settings. (I don't have access to a mac right now to look but that could be a work around until you get an answer.)

Comment: as a question about using a program, rather than a programming question around code or a code approach, this is not a question for stackoverflow but more for https://superuser.com